# 'DuplicateIdentifier', was received from the device

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I got below message
'DuplicateIdentifier', was received from the device.
when I try to run on device.Build succeed but get this message.

Comment: ru using storyboard or nib file

Comment: storyboard with **parent** and **extension** within project